# How to do a Windows 7 Image restore to an external drive?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I have a system that I have done a Windows 7 Image restore on.  I would like to migrate that image to a different hard drive.  Is there a way to restore the image to an externally connected hard drive?

For example:  I have *3 hard* drives:

1. The first in the source machine (the one I want to copy).
2. The second in a machine that I want to do the work.
3. And the third is not in a machine.  It is the target that I want to overwrite with the contents of the first.

I boot up a 2nd machine and connect the 3rd hard drive externally (using some cool cables I have).  I then use some *cool feature of Windows 7* to replace what is on the 3rd hard drive with the windows 7 image of my 1st machine (that is on on my networked backup server).

I need to know what the above mentioned "*cool feature of windows 7*" is, if there is one.  And how to use it.  Any ideas?

**Note: that I very much so don't want it to overwrite what is on the 2nd machine/hard drive.**

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to install the new drive in the PC, boot from a Windows 7 DVD and perform the System Image Recovery.

See option 2

http://www.petri.co.il/restore-windows-7-from-backup-image.htm

If you do not have a regular Windows 7 install DVD, you can make a system repair disc that will accomplish the same thing. It is smaller and can be burned to a CD if needed.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02058933&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

.